# Can an Opposing Current Create another Opposing Current?

Tags: energy-conservation, electric-current, voltage, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

In Inductors when current increases it's magnetic field induces a voltage which causes an opposing current that slows down the rise of the current that initially creates it, but can this opposing current create another opposing current that opposes the opposing current?

(Which basically means that the current is now in the same 'direction' to the very first one.) But this could keep repeating over indefinitely/infinite, doesn't this violate the law of energy conservation?

Comment: Yes it is kind of loop. But doesn't wiring resistance suffice? I might look at your Q in a too simplistic way.....